# Cómo personalizar el valor en json al exportar desde mysql

Tags: php, json, jsonp, jsonobject, jsonarray

Buen día. Alguien podría ayudarme a realizar lo siguiente.

Con esta función puedo obtener los datos de mi base de datos. y visualizarlo en formato json.

```
<?php  
 //  
 function obtenerdatos()  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jsonphp");  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM cyb_users";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $db_data = array();  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $db_data['datos'][] = array(  
                'username' => $row["username"],  
                'email'    => $row["email"],  
                'url'     =>  $row["url"]  
           );  
      }  
      return json_encode($db_data); 

 }  

echo '<pre>';
print_r(obtenerdatos());
echo'</pre>';
?>
```

del cual obtengo esto, pero NO es lo que espero que se obtenga:

```
{"datos":[{"username":"Paco","email":"thisismy@email.com","url":"www.miurl.com"},{"username":"Juan","email":"elcorreode@juan.com","url":"www.misdatosweb.org"},{"username":"Ana","email":"escribrea@ana.com","url":"www.webtodo.com"},{"username":"Javier","email":"javicho@gmail.com","url":"www.paginaweb.com"}]}
```

Habría alguna manera de poder personalizar los datos de un json, cambiando los valores de la columna username de tal manera que al obtenerlo me muestre lo siguiente, solo agregando un corchete en la columna [{"username":["usuario"]...

```
{"datos":[{"username":["Paco"],"email":"thisismy@email.com","url":"www.miurl.com"},{"username":["Juan"],"email":"elcorreode@juan.com","url":"www.misdatosweb.org"},{"username":["Ana"],"email":"escribrea@ana.com","url":"www.webtodo.com"},{"username":["Javier"],"email":"javicho@gmail.com","url":"www.paginaweb.com"}]}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Lo que obtienes es **perfecto**, un JSON válido (lo puedes verificar en [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com)). Tienes ahí un array de objetos JSON que puedes leer con suma facilidad. ¿Por qué quieres **dañar** ese resultado, produciendo un resultado complicado de leer e ilógico? ¿Qué quieres hacer luego con tu JSON? Ten en cuenta que JSON tiene que ser válido para poder luego leerlo/mostrarlo de una forma lógica. Lo que tú quieres hacer no tiene ningún sentido. En JSON esto `[]` significa un array, y ningún usuario tiene un array de `usernames`, es irreal eso.

Comment: Puedes concatenarlo manualmente, algo así: `$db_data['datos'][] = array(  
                'username' => '['.$row["username"].']',  
                'email'    => $row["email"],  
                'url'     =>  $row["url"]  
           );`

Comment: Me sirve de mucho, gracias Padre!!! :) @A.Cedano

Comment: Me arroja  lo siguiente  {"datos":[{"username":"[Paco]"... y debería ser {"datos":[{"username":["Paco"]...  llevar las comillas dentro y no afuera de los corchetes.

Comment: ¿Podrías decir por favor en qué contexto quieres usar el JSON y para qué? La única forma que veo de hacer lo que quieres es haciendo una construcción manual de tu objeto JSON, concatenando valores o algo así, sea, crearte un JSON a mano, a tu medida. Como queda el JSON originalmente puedes sacar fácilmente los nombres `Paco, Juan`, etc.

Comment: Buenos días @A.Cedano efectivamente, Tengo esto en mi pagina, 
<input type="checkbox" name="tipomarcador[]" value="tag_usuario" id="tag_usuario">
<label for="tag_usuario"><i class="fa fa-"></i>USUARIO1</label> ...
Luego se filtran mediante javascript, por tipo de usuario ya que cada uno tendrá varias visitas de campo, el cual se guardará en la base de datos, para luego cargarlo a un json. podrías orientarme y/o ayudar a que en el archivo que se exporte (json) tenga ese modelo de array en el valor del usuario ["USUARIO1"]. Gracias por tu ayuda, saludos.

Comment: No te entendí. De todos modos es mejor que pulses en [edit] para plantear mejor el problema en la misma pregunta, ya que los comentarios son muy limitados. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente. obtener el json con el formato original y recorrer todo y cambiarlo manualmente.

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('25-04-2019.json'); 
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
 //activity_code "1" 
 foreach ($data as $key => $entry) 
 { if ($entry['username'] == 'Paco') 
    { $data[$key]['username'] = '['.'Paco'.']';
    } 

} 
//cuando realizo la salida del archivo enformato json me cambia siempre con su sintaxis
//el username mantiene su "[Paco]".
 $newJsonString = json_encode($data); file_put_contents('jsonFile.json', $newJsonString); 
?>
```

Alguna otra solución para poder  recorrer todos los usuarios, modificarlos y guardar el archivo pero no en formato JSON ya que se cambiaría nuevamente a su formato preestablecido, alguna solución por favor.

Comment: esta es la solución a tu problema?

Comment: la solución efectiva al problema sería agregarle un array($row["username"]); de esta manera logré que me muestre los que necesitaba, gracias por vuestra ayuda, saludos!!! ;)